# Use ffprobe to view audio tracks by language

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I wish to use ffprobe to list all audio streams, and show what language is used.

Simply this is part of me trying to find ways to automatically remove non-english tracks from video files.

I am new to ffprobe, but have had some experience using ffmpeg.

Because I know that there is no guarantee of what order the language tracks may be.

That is why I think it is vital to list each track, by number, then language, then when I know this part works, figure out how to remove the non-english ones.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I wouldn't bother wasting your time asking on StackOverflow. You'll end up getting downvoted and vote to close because the question is not programming rleated. It's stupid I know, but it happened to me. If you look at all the new ffmpeg questions on SO many are downvoted.

Answer (score 11):

Running this ffprobe command

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

will produce this output

```
1|eng
2|deu
3|eng
4|eng
5|fre
```

The first value is the absolute stream index, and the 2nd value the language tag assigned.

To remove only and all english tagged audio streams, run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -map -0:m:language:eng NoEng.mp4
```

To keep only english tagged audio streams, run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:eng OnlyEng.mp4
```

Comment: What about a command to remove all non-english audio tracks.

Comment: Let me clarify, what If I wanted to keep the english but remove all other audio tracks, how do i do that?

Comment: @Gyan JSON output posible ?

Comment: Yes, using `-of json`